# PHP session disappears while opening the page in a new tab using www

Tags: php, mysql, session

I am using PHP sessions. I set the session using session_start() and set some session variables. Then, I use those session variables.

Now, say I open a page in my browser (http://example.com) and a PHP session starts. If I open another page in a new tab (http://www.example.com , notice www in the URL) the first session disappears.

What can be the solution to avoid this situation ?

Comment: Any reason to use inconsistent domain name? Cannot you just always use domain with `www` or without `www`, as everyone does.

Answer (score 2):

Your session ID is stored in a cookie; cookies are only valid for specific domains. To brute force this problem, you need to use [`session_set_cookie_params`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) (before `session_start`) to make sure the cookie is valid on all subdomains you are interested in (the `$domain` argument controls this).

However, a better approach would be to set up a permanent redirect from one of the domains to the other at the web server level; if you have a public site and you care about your search engine ratings at all it is *imperative* to do this in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Actually what you should do, unless you have **very good** reasons to don't do it, is to use just one url. As far as I know it wasn't very SEO friendly to have different url to access the same content as the browser engines consider it duplicated content.

You should configure it to use the www always or don't use it at all. Fairly easy to do with the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: actually, I am using one url only, but when I used google API for importing contacts, the redirect uri was with www and in the redirected url I wanted my sessions to be set.